# Postfix: block email from sender only for certain recipient

Tags: postfix

I'd like to reject email from senders, but only for certain recipients. Example:

Sender `a@sender.com` is blocked for `b@recipient.com`.
Sender `c@sender.com` is blocked for `d@recipient.com`.

...

But all other recipients can receive mails from `a@sender.com` and `c@sender.com`. I am also using hosting multiple domains on the very same Postfix.

I found solutions like these https://dan.langille.org/2019/01/25/using-postfix-to-block-mail-based-on-from-sender-and-to-recipient/

They suggest using `smtpd_restriction_classes`. But this does not scale well, because if I would have to set 50 rules (sender-recipient pairs), I would need to create 50 files, with 50 classes. That's tedious.

Is there a better solution in Postfix?

Comment: You will find that what *"scales well"* highly depends on which software you can carry the operational cost for, possibly for years to come. I'd slap on a dead simple script, integrated through the policy daemon or milter interface. But if you already have something like rspamd or spamassassin setup in a suitable setup, you might instead want to put your complex rules there.

Comment: If your results are only "no match" and "reject", you should have a choice with the lookup order. If you think of your rules as per-recipient groups now and conclude you will need 50 restriction classes.. can you possibly think of your rules as per-sender groups and drastically fold the number of lookups for the recipient side because inside those subgroups the mapping can be expressed as one or few pcre patterns?